# ConcurrentModificationException while collecting hashmaps into an ArrayList using Java stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, concurrentmodification

I have a weird problem with the code, that is throwing a CME. I know for sure that the CME would be thrown when the collection or the map is being modified while iterating over the same, but I am not doing anything as such here.

Code snippet from `AllocatorCache`:

```
public AllocationData getLatest(String allocId) {
        FxAllocatorCacheBean cachedAllocData = computeIfAbsentBeanForAllocId(allocId);
        Collection<Map<Integer, Object>> tagmaps = cachedAllocData.getRecords().stream().map(row -> new HashMap<>(row.getRowMap())).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList ::new));
        return (new AllocationData(allocId,tagmaps,cachedAllocData.getAllocStatus(),cachedAllocData.getAllocationSourceType()));
    }

public FxAllocatorCacheBean computeIfAbsentBeanForAllocId(String allocId) {
        return allocIdToAllocBeanMap.computeIfAbsent(allocId, f -> new FxAllocatorCacheBean(allocId));
    }
```

The above code is throwing the CME.

```
[LOGGED STACK TRACE BEGIN] 
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1445)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1479)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1477)
    at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:512)
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:490)
    at com.allocation.cache.AllocatorCache.lambda$getLatest$7(FxAllocatorCache.java:330)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.allocation.cache.AllocatorCache.getLatest(FxAllocatorCache.java:330)
```

where line 330 in AllocatorCache is this:

```
Collection<Map<Integer, Object>> tagmaps = cachedAllocData.getRecords().stream().map(row -> new HashMap<>(row.getRowMap())).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList ::new));
```

The `cachedAllocData.getRecords()` will give a `List<RowData>`, where `RowData` is simply a wrapper of a HashMap.

Code snippet for RowData class:

```
class RowData {
   private Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

   public RowData(Map<Integer, Object> map) {
      this.map = map;
   }

   public Map<Integer, Object> getRowMap() {
      return map;
   }
}
```

Can someone please give me a hint on where it is going wrong? Happy to provide more details if needed.

Edit:
I have tried to reproduce this issue by writing a simple program like this, but no luck whatsoever.

```
public class RaviTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {
            start();
        }
    }
    
    private static void start() {
        AllocatorCache cache = FxAllocatorCache.INSTANCE;
        cache.computeIfAbsentBeanForAllocId("AllocId1234");
        FxAllocatorCacheBean bean = cache.computeIfAbsentBeanForAllocId("AllocId1234");
        bean.setRecords(getDummyRecords());
        
        new Thread(() -> {
            FxAllocatorCacheBean cachedAllocData = cache.computeIfAbsentBeanForAllocId("AllocId1234");
            Collection<Map<Integer, Object>> tagmaps = cachedAllocData.getRecords().stream()
                    .map(row -> {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return new HashMap<>(row.getRowMap());
                    }).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
            System.out.println(tagmaps);
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            FxAllocatorCacheBean cachedAllocData = cache.computeIfAbsentBeanForAllocId("AllocId1234");
            List<FxRowDataAccess> records = cachedAllocData.getRecords();
            records.forEach(record -> {
                record.getRowMap().put(1, "Test");
                record.getRowMap().remove(100);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            records.forEach(record -> {
                record.getRowMap().put(2, "Test");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }).start();
    }

    private static List<RowData> getDummyRecords() {
        final List<RowData> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            RowData row = new RowData(new HashMap<>());
            row.getRowMap().put(100, "AllocId1234");
            ret.add(row);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks, updated the question with the details. Thanks

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks, but if that is the case, it should happen consistently right? But that's not the case. This is the first occurrence out of maybe 1000 calls to the same API.

Comment: `new HashMap<>(row.getRowMap())` is creating a copy of the map. Since no-one can have a reference to the newly created map, it must be the map returned by `getRowMap()` which is modified while the copying is in progress. The only way this is possible, is by a different thread. In that case, you can not expect consistent behavior. It may happen to work one time, throw another time, and silently produce corrupted data yet another time.

Comment: @Holger,I tried to write a program to reproduce this issue, but couldn't do it. Please see the updated details

Comment: Performing concurrent modifications on a data structure that is not thread safe, will lead to unreliable behaviors, including those that you can’t reproduce on purpose. Don’t waste your time by trying to reproduce it. Try to fix your program by precluding concurrent modifications instead.

Comment: So what is the fix for this? Making the map in the RowData class a concurrent map?

Comment: No, that would only make the exception disappear but not solve the semantic problem. You are trying to create an object that is kind of a snapshot of the current data. You can not expecting consistent data when someone is modifying the data while you are copying them. This is a fundamental problem of your application. We can’t tell you how to fix it, as we don’t know anything about your application. It boils down to a) ensure that all operations that might modify the data have finished or b) prevent those operations from modifying the data while you’re copying.

Comment: Ok understood @Holger. Thanks for the suggestions